# How to add field descriptions programmatically in BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to **add field description** in a bq table programmatically, I know how to do in UI. 
I have this requirement because I have few tables in my dataset which are refreshed on a daily basis and we use **"writeMode": "WRITE_TRUNCATE"**. This also deletes the description of all the field names of the table.

I have also added the description in my schema file for the table, like this

```
                    {
                            "name" : "tax",
                            "type" : "FLOAT",
                            "description" : "Tax amount customer paid"
                    }
```

But I don't see the descriptions in my final table after running the scripts to load data.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are providing a schema with the load job that is specifying WRITE_TRUNCATE? If you are, then you can include "description" with the schema (see my answer below). If you are not, then I suspect you are inheriting the original destination table's schema, which should have included the original description. If this is the case it sounds like a bug: can you provide a project_id:job_id of a job that hit this problem? Post here or email msheldon@google.com, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some Tables API (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables) allow you to set table and schema's fields descriptions

You can set descriptions during
table **creation** - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/insert
or after table created using one of below APIs:
**Patch** - 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/patch
or **Update**  - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/update

I think, in your case Patch API is more suitable
Below link shows you table resources you can set with those APIs
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery load jobs accept a schema that includes "description" with each field.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load

If you specify the description along with each field you are creating during your WRITE_TRUNCATE operation, the descriptions should be applied to the destination table.

Here's a snippet from the above link that includes the schema you are specifying:

```
"load": {
  "sourceUris": [
    string
  ],
  "schema": {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": string,
        "type": string,
        "mode": string,
        "fields": [
          (TableFieldSchema)
        ],
        "description": string
      }
    ]
  },
```